# Java 8 localdate parsing issue

Tags: java-8, jackson

I have declared variables as localdate in my pojo class. I have done everything but my date is converting to yyyy-MM-dd but I want to read dd/MM/yyyy. I have done all the pom entries. Its been 2 days but I am not able to resolve this issue. I am using objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType for parsing list.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate date;

private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constant.dateFormat);
protected LocalDateDeserializer() {
    super(LocalDate.class);
}

@Override
public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return LocalDate.parse(jp.readValueAs(String.class), formatter);
}


public LocalDateSerializer() {
    super(LocalDate.class);
}

@Override
public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sp)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    gen.writeString(value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constant.dateFormat)));
}

objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Comment: If you are using `JavaTimeModule` you do not need to implement custom serialiser and deserialiser. Property should look like this: `@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") private LocalDate date;` Remove `JsonDeserialize` and `JsonSerialize` annotations.

Comment: I have used all the permutations combination, even after removing it is not working

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use? Could you create and post [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows that problem?

Comment: I am using 2.10.2 version

Comment: Just out of curiosity asking, are you using with Spring Boot or just Java?

Comment: I've checked in `Java` console application and it works properly.